# iOS simulator won't turn on

Tags: macos, xcode, ios

I'm running:

- OSX 10.8.5.
- iOS simulator 4.2
- Xcode 5.0.1

I want to open up the iOS simulator so I can run mobile Safari and test some sites. However, while the simulator launches, it never turns on. I just have a blank device screen.

Clicking the home button does nothing. "Reset Content and Settings" does nothing. Using Hardware > Home does nothing.

Any ideas as to why it's not launching?

Comment: How about other iOS Simulators, e.g. 6.1 ?

Comment: Did you turn it off and on again? :D

Comment: @MattClark I even uninstalled extensions!

Answer (score 0):

This may be user error. This may be Apple error. :)

Here's the problem:

If I go to the search tool in OS X, type in "iOS Simulator" and launch the app from there, It launches  iOS simulator 4.2.

If I instead open Xcode 5, create a blank iOS project, run that, it will launch iOS simulator 7.0. Which works.

So I don't know exactly what's going on. Is iOS simulator now just built in to Xcode and not launch-able as a stand-alone app?

Not the end of the world, but it's kind of annoying to have to run a project from Xcode just to get the simulator up.